# innerHTML.replace not working in firefox but in IE

Tags: javascript, firefox, innerhtml

I want to rename the onclick method of a button. First my Button has following code:

```
<input id="my_button" class="update field-button" type="button" onclick="add( this )" value="ADD Something" title="ADD Item" name="my_button"></input>
```

Then I want something like this:

```
<input id="my_button" class="update field-button" type="button" onclick="remove( this )" value="ADD Something" title="ADD Item" name="my_button"></input>
```

**I do the rename with this statement:**

```
parentNode.innerHTML = parentNode.innerHTML.replace( /(onclick="?)[A-Za-z0-9\-]+(\([^)]*\)"?)/, "$1remove$2" );
```

`parentNode` is a var:

```
var parentNode = removeButton.parentNode;
```

**In the Internet Explorer it works, but not in firefox**

Comment: I would suggest just running a single function and have the logic that determines whether it's an add or remove within that function, rather than attempting to change the handler like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I would recommend the rich's answer and put that logic into the clickhandler, it might be interesting what your problem is.

Firefox does your replacement correctly and calls the buttons native remove-method as the click handler has the buttons's scope. So

```
onclick="remove( this )"
```

is the same as

```
onclick="document.getElementById('my_button').remove();"
```

and the button gets removed from the dom.

Answer (score 2):

This is not the way to achieve your desired functionality, click handlers can be bound entirely with javascript.

Try the following:

```
document.getElementById('my_button').onclick = function() {
  var toggle = false;
  return function (e) {
    toggle = !toggle;
    toggle ? add(this) : remove(this);
  };
}();
```